# Prejudicial vs. Prejudiced?

Tags: synonyms

Is there a meaningful difference between the adjectives "prejudicial" and prejudiced"? Does each word fit better in a certain context?

(By "prejudicial", I am not referring to the "detrimental" definition, but the "premature judgment" definition).

Comment: Can you link to the exact 'premature judgement' definition that you're referring to (for prejudicial)?

Comment: @Alok Merriam-Webster: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/prejudicial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something is **prejudicial** is it is inclined to induce prejudice in someone who is aware of it.  Such a person is thus **prejudiced**.

A wise judge will not allow the prosecution to introduce gory crime-scene photographs because they will be **prejudicial**.  That is, the horror the pictures will produce in the minds of the jurors will lead them to ignore the actual evidence of whether the defendant is responsible.  These jurors will be **prejudiced**, unable to make a fair-minded judgment on all the evidence.

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, _objects_ are prejudicial, whereas _people_ are prejudiced?

Comment: Only people can be prejudiced, because we consider that only our species is advanced enough to form judgments, ahead of the evidence or otherwise.  But certainly people's actions may be prejudicial.  To continue with the legal trope, a judge may exclude witness testimony if it's determined to be prejudicial.